# Polymorphic relations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a `Link` model, which needs a field that refers to either the `Page`, `Redirect` or `Gallery` model. I would like to be able to do something line `$link->obj` and have that return either the Page, Redirect or Gallery object depending on which one was saved to it.

[Polymorphic relations](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#polymorphic-relations) appear to be what I'm looking for, except that I can't seem to get this approach to work.

## Current code

```
<?php

$item = Page::find (1);

$link = new Link ();
$link->linkable ()->save ($item);
$link->save ();
```

### Models

```
<?php

class Link extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'link';

    public function linkable ()
    {
        return $this->morphTo ();
    }
}

class Page extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'page';

    public function linkable ()
    {
        return $this->morphOne ('Link', 'linkable');
    }
}

class Redirect extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'redirect';

    public function linkable ()
    {
        return $this->morphOne ('Link', 'linkable');
    }
}

class Gallery extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'gallery';

    public function linkable ()
    {
        return $this->morphOne ('Link', 'linkable');
    }
}
```

The `link`  database table has `linkable_id` and `linkable_type` fields.

I suppose I must be misunderstanding the documentation, because this does not appear to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. Assuming you have your database setup correctly, the only issue I see is you calling `save()` on the `morphTo` relationship.

The `morphTo` side of the relationship is the `belongsTo` side. The `belongsTo` side does not use the `save()` method, it uses the `associate()` method.

So, the code you're looking for should be something like:

```
$item = Page::find(1);

$link = new Link();
$link->linkable()->associate($item); // associate the belongsTo side
$link->save();

// and to show it worked:
$link->load('linkable');
$page = $link->linkable;
echo get_class($page); // prints "Page"
```

Comment: I had already tried that, and it didn't work at the time. What I didn't realise however is that I made a typo causing `$item` to be `NULL`, and since Laravel 4.2's error handling is broken on PHP 7 I didn't get any very useful error messages ^^ Thanks!